# Exporting dataframe by write.csv

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data like following

```
class.df <- data.frame(
  A = sample(1:2, 100, replace=TRUE), 
  B = sample(1:2, 100, replace=TRUE), 
  C = sample(1:2, 100, replace=TRUE), 
  D = sample(1:2, 100, replace=TRUE)
)

ids_df <- t(combn(names(class.df), 2))
fisher_tests <- apply(ids_df, 1, function(i) tryCatch(fisher.test(table(class.df[,i])), error = function(e) NA_real_))
edge_table <- cbind(ids_df, t(sapply(fisher_tests, "[", c("p.value", "estimate"))))
edge_table



           p.value   estimate 
[1,] "A" "B" 0.6826874 0.7919741
[2,] "A" "C" 0.6873498 1.219358 
[3,] "A" "D" 0.5473441 0.7356341
[4,] "B" "C" 0.6828843 0.8164863
[5,] "B" "D" 1         1.033625 
[6,] "C" "D" 0.2257244 0.5789776
```

> `write.csv(edge_table,"/Users/Results/EE2.csv")`

But when i try to write.csv and open the csv file. The last column (estimate) shows weird values of matrix like following. I just need numerical values as it was showing in R. How to resolve the issue.

[image]

Comment: Can you show your code for export (write.csv code line)

Comment: write.csv(edge_table,"/Users/Results/EE2.csv")

Comment: You edge_table already has a weird format, you have 2 colnames since you should have 4

Comment: Try `ids_df <- as.data.frame(t(combn(names(class.df), 2)))`. You are creating a matrix rather than a data frame, and the fourth column is a list, which is why it appears this way when you read it back in

Comment: @AllanCameron While doing that and then writing csv file i am getting error  " Error in utils::write.table(unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'.

Comment: just use `data.table::fwrite(edge_table,".../EE2.csv")` - faster, more reliable and handles its default setting better - so it works as is

Comment: I am assuming the issue is due to output pattern of Fisher test here.

Comment: Yes, the Fisher test output is a list. You are creating a list-array with `t(sapply(fisher_tests, "[", c("p.value", "estimate")))`. See my answer below, which specifically unlists the results.

Answer (score 0):

Your `edge_table` object is an array that contains list columns due to the way you have created it. If you want a standard data frame, you can try:

```r
edge_table <- as.data.frame(edge_table)
edge_table[] <- lapply(edge_table, unlist)

write.csv(edge_table, 'test.csv', row.names = FALSE)

read.csv('test.csv')
#>   V1 V2   p.value  estimate
#> 1  A  B 0.2372953 0.6160489
#> 2  A  C 0.3164033 1.6070638
#> 3  A  D 0.3238934 1.5017413
#> 4  B  C 0.8411522 1.1562830
#> 5  B  D 0.6882391 0.8017990
#> 6  C  D 0.5514280 1.2965724
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: In my actual data set. I am getting this error

 Error in data.frame(p.value = x$p.value, estimate = x$estimate) : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

Comment: While running this command. edge_table <- cbind(ids_df, do.call(rbind, lapply(fisher_tests, function(x) {
  data.frame(p.value = x$p.value, estimate = x$estimate)
})))

Comment: @Aryh try my updated version - this should handle the cases when the fisher test returns an error (which I think is what makes it fail on your real data).

Comment: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : subscript out of bounds

Comment: @Aryh did you change the way `fisher_tests` is produced in my example (note the different value in the `error` function within the `tryCatch`) - you shouldn't be getting that error with this version. If you are, can you post a reproducible example of data that causes the problem? Thanks

Comment: While using exactly this code on my real data. Now i am getting error. 
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1

Comment: @Aryh can you post some data that reproduces the problem? The code works fine on the example you posted. It's difficult to fix the problem if we can't reproduce it.

Comment: The real data contains around 1000 rows . I am not sure how to produce reproducible example out of this. Is there any other way to do Fisher test by forloop may be? My main objective is I need the p value and estimate out put from fisher test against ids_df. The main issue is due to the format of "estimate" in fishers test.  Is there any way i can change the output of last column from my csv file (the one i showed in main question) to numerical!!!! Just looking for any possible solution!!!

Comment: @Aryh see my update. If you  convert `edge_table` to a data frame, then `unlist` all the list columns, you should get the result you want.